# MySQL Code Works in PHPMyAdmin but not in PHP Page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run this query in PHPMyAdmin it works fine:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Taskers (Taskers.MemberID, Taskers.EventID) VALUES ($memberid, $eventid)";
```

...but when I run it from the PHP page using the `$sql` command, I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax.....near ')' at line 2

The Taskers table uses foreign keys to relate to the primary keys in the Members and Events tables. The Taskers table also has the primary key `TaskerID`. which auto-increments.

I double checked: both `$memberid` and `$eventid` are set to integers.

I looked at the general log and, strangely, the query is not showing up. Running a quick test, it seems that only `SELECT` queries are showing up in the general log, but no `DROP` or `INSERT` commands are showing up.

Comment: Stop, and research SQL injection vulnerabilities.  You should never concatenate your variables into queries like this.  There are massive potential security holes waiting for you.  Even if the values come from a safe place now, that's not a good reason to build queries this way.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT! I had to explicitly set my PHP variable types to integer after normalizing them from the Http POST function...

```
settype($foo, "integer");
```

...and then use them in the MySQL query.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Taskers (Taskers.MemberID, Taskers.EventID) VALUES (".$memberid.",".$eventid.")";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this time I received error "Data truncated for column 'MemberID' at row 1".